# Not able to fetch the varibale value inside the data key in the response

Tags: jmeter

When i am passing the userName as a variable inside data key in the below request then not able to fetch the value. I got the userName in the Login request response. Here UserName and playerName are the same.

Login Request:

42[
"get_login",
{
"key": "AUEEW891WL",
"socketId":"${sid}",
"username": "",
"avatar": "",
"language": "en",
"playerMove": "",
"joinGame": "",
"replay": 0,
"gameID": 0,
"gameNo": 0,
"data": "&email=llk${counter5}@gmail.com&password=poker",
"players": 0,
"level": "",
"lastAction": "",
"game": "",
"playMoney": 1,
"role": ""
}
]

**Response:**

42[
"gotLogin",
{
"response": {
"playerId": 25601,
"totalWin": 0,
"points": 0,
"playerName": "673508846384",
"displayName": "llk45",
"playerRank": "Amateur",
"playerBank": "11K",
"playerBankAmount": 11000,
"playerAvatar": "avatar1.jpg",
"playerEmail": "llk45@gmail.com",
"playerLevel": 1,
"playerLevelStr": "Lvl. 1",
"playerLevelPrg": 0,
"playerLevelPoints": 100,
"playerGold": 0,
"playerDealerId": 1,
"playerFbId": "",
"loadVocab": "",
"dailyBonus": 0,
"token": "0a5260592b6efc02d3102c639eac0f60d91ad7de8bf57fa114da179f05bcfa84",
"ip": "182.74.4.226",
"interface": {
"home": [
{
"buttonTitle": "Casino",
"buttonIcon": "casino-icon",
"buttonAction": {
"type": "function",
"name": "loadLobby"
}
},
{
"buttonTitle": "Leagues",
"buttonIcon": "leagues-icon",
"buttonAction": {
"type": "function",
"name": "loadLobby"
}
},
{
"buttonTitle": "Clubs",
"buttonIcon": "clubs-icon",
"buttonAction": {
"type": "function",
"name": "loadLobby"
}
},
{
"buttonTitle": "Cashier",
"buttonIcon": "cashier-icon",
"buttonAction": {
"type": "panel",
"name": "pnlChipStore"
}
},
{
"buttonTitle": "Settings",
"buttonIcon": "settings-icon",
"buttonAction": {
"type": "panel",
"name": "pnlSettings"
}
},
{
"buttonTitle": "Notifications",
"buttonIcon": "notifications-icon",
"buttonAction": {
"type": "panel",
"name": "pnlLevel"
}
}
]
},
"playerCountry": "IN",
"role": 1
}
}
]

**Request:**

42[
"create_game",
{
"key": "AUEEW891WL",
"socketId":"${sid}",
"username": ${userName}",
"avatar": "avatar17.jpg",
"language": "en",
"playerMove": "",
"joinGame": "",
"replay": 0,
"gameID": 0,
"gameNo": 0,
"data": "&gameID=undefined&game=texas&playMoney=1&gameStyle=private-cashgame&tableName=llkTable${counter1}&rakeRate=0&speed=60&sb=10&bb=20&tablelow=100&tablelimit=1000&videorequired=false&username=${userName}",
"players": 0,
"level": 347,
"lastAction": "",
"game": "",
"playMoney": 1,
"role": "1",
"token":"${token}",
"playerId":"${playerId}"
}
]

**Response Request:**

42[
"create_game",
{
"key": "AUEEW891WL",
"socketId":"TRV8Rm_jtsqn_BBFAAiM",
"username": "673508846384",
"avatar": "avatar17.jpg",
"language": "en",
"playerMove": "",
"joinGame": "",
"replay": 0,
"gameID": 0,
"gameNo": 0,
"data": "&gameID=undefined&game=texas&playMoney=1&gameStyle=private-cashgame&tableName=llkTable47&rakeRate=0&speed=60&sb=10&bb=20&tablelow=100&tablelimit=1000&videorequired=false&username="673508846384",
"players": 0,
"level": 347,
"lastAction": "",
"game": "",
"playMoney": 1,
"role": "1",
"token":"0a5260592b6efc02d3102c639eac0f60d91ad7de8bf57fa114da179f05bcfa84",
"playerId":"25601"
}
]

Here is the screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hqtn.png)

How can i pass this value in the create game request inside the data key to fetch it?

Comment: don't add pictures and your question is not a clear.

Answer (score 0):

If your `${userName}` variable has value (i.e. it was set via [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) or comes from a [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) or it's from the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)) - JMeter will send the value in the request.

If the variable doesn't have the value - JMeter will send `${userName}`

So double check that the `${userName}` variable:

1. Exists
2. Has its respective value

It can be done using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter).

[image]